# How to make event occur only at the first time of app load Angular 8

Tags: angular

I want an event to occur only at the first time of the document load. How do I do it in angular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just perform it in the app.component.ts. Add the method in your `AppComponent` class & fire the event with the help of `ngOnInit` method.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're talking about a specific Angular component. If you have finished with the template in your `component-name.component.html`, you can start connecting it to your back-end in the typescript part of the component `component-name.component.ts` (it's located in the same folder).

Per default it looks like this:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-name',
  templateUrl: './component-name.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component-name.component.css'] // or './component-name.component.scss' depending on your setup.
})
export class ProposalsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

The `ngOnInit()` method will be called *on init* (on load of your component body). As mentioned above you can also do `ngAfterViewInit()`, but I really suggest you to keep your code up-to the documentation and do anything in `ngOnInit()`.